# Java Scanner Taking Extra Input

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a `switch` statement that takes inputs with `Scanner`, and when I run in NetBeans, one of the inputs takes an extra blank input. The extra input happens at variable `dateAdmission` when the user is asked to input "Enter date of admission".

```
case "patient":
{
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Address: ");
    String address = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter date of birth: ");
    String dob = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter MCP number: ");
    int mcp = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter date of admission: ");
    String dateAdmission = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    String hospital = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter name of doctor: ");
    String doctor = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter room number: ");
    int roomNum = in.nextInt();
    a[i] = new Patient(name, address, dob, mcp, dateAdmission, hospital, doctor, roomNum);
    break;
}
```

Comment: `String hospital = in.nextLine();` either get rid of this or understand why its there and make use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have forgotten to provide `System.out.println("Enter hospital");`
before the

```
String hospital = in.nextLine();
```

What happened was it printed nothing and took the extra input for hospital?

Comment: Umm...What it has to do with question?

Comment: Since there was just System.out.println() without argument, it prints a blank line and expects for input, since the next line is hospital = in.nextLine(). This is where his extra input came.

Comment: ohh yeah...nice observation ;) correct answer +1..and welcome to s.o. don't comment questions in your answer.